# How to make a user authentication using hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

i have a current channel of hyperledger fabric with chaincode that does CRUD operations my question is that is there any way to make a method in a chaincode that registers the new user when certain condition match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of several methods to get the identity of the user:

- `GetCreator`
- `GetId`
- `GetMSPId`

They are part of the Client Identity Chaincode Library, documented here: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/pkg/cid#section-readme

The Hyperledger Fabric docs provide some help for access control also if you're interested in that: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private-data/private-data.html?highlight=getmspid#private-data-sharing-patterns

Comment: my actual question is that is there any method that can store the user id and get created a new user. This method will only return the user data not store it.

Comment: Users are created using the MSP. You cannot create user identities from chaincode. https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployguide/use_CA.html

You can use fabric-ca-client if you're using Fabric CA (the default)